# How to efficiently translate website content with php, keeping it SEO friendly?

Tags: php, seo, translate

This is the scenario:

I have a website that I'll translate and eventually apply a good SEO on it.
Which method is best for translate the content (menu links, about 10 articles, alt tags, title tags, meta tags, html lang, etc) while being easely indexed by Google, Bing, Yandex and other search engines?

My first idea is to use a translate php function that consists of arrays made by myself (I have a prototyope of it already) that takes the content and displays it in the user's language.

Is this the right path? the problem here is that I wanted to be sure to have a dynamic system that allows me to add a new language in the future.

Maybe MySql is the right choice?

The website doesn't use a cms, I made it by myself with php though I have no problem to rely on MySql if I need to.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store all texts inside a db and apply another field for language:

```
+----+---------+---------+
| id | text_en | text_de |
+----+---------+---------+
|  1 | English | Deutch  |
+----+---------+---------+
```

Now, when user switches languages, just use the field for that language:

```
$lang = 'en';
$query = "SELECT text_".$lang." FROM texts WHERE id = 1";
```

Something like that. So, all your client side texts will be stored inside the db at all times. So your output will be like:

```
<div id="header"><?=get_db_text_for_id(1)?></div>
```

Of course, you need precautions and some more field, but thats the general idea.

Comment: Thank you, in the end I used your method :)

Answer (score 4):

You've basically got 3 choices and there are pros and cons to each:

**1:** as Dainis Abols suggests, chuck it in the database - depending on how your server is set up this could be the slowest, most system heavy route (it's all relative though, it's unlikely to make any difference unless you're getting millions of view an hour).

**2:** use PHP library files; I tend to use library files for small, single items like field labels (forename, surname etc) and store larger things like CMS-managed HTML in the database... this reduces the database calls but adds a small overhead for each dictionary you load into a script `<?php $this->page->dictionary->product = Dictionary::load("product"); ?>` sort of thing.

**3:** finally, I personally think it's worth taking a look at PHP's implementation of [gettext](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php) though you'll need something like [poedit](http://www.poedit.net/) to maintain the PO (compressed translation files). This gives you the ability to very rapidly maintain translations as you just enter the text in your PHP document by wrapping it in a simple underscore function:

e.g. `<?= _("Hello World"); ?>`

You then maintain the translations in compressed PO files - it's very efficient (potentially faster than doing it with native PHP files) however it does have some drawbacks when it comes to the nuances of natural language.

As an example, if you have a field label "title" `<?= _("Title"); ?>` then all instances of `_("Title")` will be translated in the same way.

This means you can't use "Title" as both a form label for a person's title and as the title of a book; for instance, in German, you may want to use *Anrede* for one "Title" and *Titel* for the other.

Although, to really use `gettext` you'd probably need to be running your own server - it can require an Apache reboot when you change the PO files :\

As for **Search Engines** they read the output from your code so it doesn't really make a lot of difference which method you use to perform the translations but ideally you may want to keep the URLs RESTful so whether you're including PHP dictionaries, calling the database or using gettext (or changing your mind from one to another later), you'll be able to map the language to the URL with something like `http://www.mysite.com/en_gb/widgets` so you can change *how* the program works without changing the URLs.