# PHP Creating variables list from Mysql database

Tags: php, mysqli

I've a database that using for 3 languages this way:

```
id  name    de_de   al_sq
1   title   titel   titulli
2   points  punkte  pike
```

Now when in php $lang is set to 'al_sq':

```
$lang = 'al_sq';
```

I'm trying to generate variables using names of that language, in this case:

```
$langtitle = 'titulli';
$langpoints = 'pike';
```

Trying something like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `langs`";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $lang{$row["lang"]} = $row[$lang];
  }
}
```

but something is not good, how to generate these variables?

Comment: You have an unmatched curly brace after `$lang` on the 5th row.

Comment: What happens when you use the code you posted?

Comment: If you try to roll your own localization system like this you're going to have a very bad time. Use something like [Gettext](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php) and save yourself a lot of future trouble.

Comment: @Sammitch - there are certain limitations with Gettext though; you can't deal with linguistic nuances on very sort strings, for instance by *"save"* do you mean *"enregistrer"* (button on a form) or *"économisez"* (save 10%)... and you have to reboot Apache every time you change the .po files - that's if you can even get it working if you're developing on a Windows box.

Comment: You might try matching the `{` with a `}`

Comment: @CD001 yes there are edge cases and caveats to Gettext, but I had a dev implement localization like OP here which instantly overpowered the database on release. The level of interaction with the backend store required by localization like this grows exponentially and will absolutely demolish you with overhead. Feel free to suggest an alternative to Gettext, but I unequivocally recommend _against_ anyone pursuing localization storage in mysql or any other DBMS.

Comment: @Sammitch - oddly enough I had a vague recollection that I'd answered a question like this a while ago - [turns out it was 6 years ago!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261748/how-to-efficiently-translate-website-content-with-php-keeping-it-seo-friendly/14262477#14262477). Hasn't changed much, I'd probably use a static translation class now for short strings (e.g. from an array `button_save => "enregistrer"`), and the database for big chunks of text (e.g. HTML from the CMS); not quite as efficient as Gettext but much easier to manage, especially when developing on a Windows box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a minor syntax error in your code, which causes an error. What you need to do here is to:

1. Fetch the `name` and `al_sq` columns from the database table. This is done by selecting the value of `$lang` (based on your code). For security reasons, the value of `$lang` is protected against SQL injection, as you did not specify where the value was coming from.
2. Then you must check if there was any results, and in the case there wasn't any, it will simply terminate the script with an error.
3. Then lastly you must iterate over each row of the returned results, and do a variable variable assignment. This will make `$langpoints` etc. work (and any other you may add in the future).

Code:

```
$sql = 'SELECT `name`, `' . $conn->real_escape_string($lang) . '` FROM `langs`';

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if (!$result || !$result->num_rows) {
  echo 'Invalid language selected';
  exit;
}

while ($phrase = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  ${'lang' . $phrase['name']} = $phrase[$lang];
}

// $langtitle
// $langpoints
```

Comment: Yes you understanded what I want, but if you can check again it showing this error:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetchAssoc() in /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/testapp/public/lang.php:24 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/testapp/public/lang.php on line 24

Comment: Based on your code, I've changed to my code with: ${'lang' . $row['name']} = $row[$lang];
and now is working, thank you.

Comment: @AlbaStar I had a minor typo (fetchAssoc() should have been fetch_assoc()), glad you got it working \o/

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using the database as a key-value store with multiple value fields depending on the language, you could use `PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR` so it returns an array with the name as the key. This way you also avoid loading the data for other languages that you might not need at all:

```
    $query = "SELECT `name`, :column as value FROM `langs`";
    $statement = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute(["column"  => $lang]);
    $data = $statement->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);

    // $data becomes an array with the name as the key:
    $langtitle = $data['title'];
    $langpoints = $data['points'];
```

Make sure, if the user provides the value for `$lang`, to check that it is a valid column value.

Comment: By using this code, the author must alter `$conn` to be an instance of PDO, instead of mysqli (like in his snippet)

Answer (score 1):

This should be close to what you are wanting based on how your database is presented. Scaling up would be clunky though if there is more the title and points stored.

```
$lang = 'al_sq';
$sql = "SELECT $lang FROM 'langs'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 $langtitle = $row[1];
 $langpoints = $row[2];
 }
}
```